# Best to way delete log records that are older than 60 days

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two log tables in our database to which all of our applications will be writing logs to. We are planning to create a cron job everyday to delete records older than 60 days.

Both the tables doesn't have any primary keys. Below is the table DDL for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE AUDITLOG
( 
  UUID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  INTERFACEID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  APPLICATIONNAME varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  COMPONENTNAME varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  SOURCEAPPLICATIONNAME varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  TARGETAPPLICATIONNAME varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  MESSAGE varchar2(400) NOT NULL,
  ENGINENAME varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP timestamp,
  TIMESTAMP timestamp,
  EXCEPTION CLOB,
  LOGTYPE varchar2(20) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONLOG
( 
  UUID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  INTERFACEID varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  APPLICATIONNAME varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP timestamp,
  TIMESTAMP timestamp,
  EVENTPAYLOAD CLOB,
  LOGTYPE varchar2(20) NOT NULL
);


CREATE INDEX AUDITLOG_UUID_IDX ON AUDITLOG(UUID);
CREATE INDEX AUDITLOG_TIMESTAMP_IDX ON AUDITLOG(TIMESTAMP);
CREATE INDEX TRANSACTIONLOG_UUID_IDX ON TRANSACTIONLOG(UUID);
CREATE INDEX TRANSACTIONLOG_TIMESTAMP_IDX ON TRANSACTIONLOG(TIMESTAMP);
```

Being not a DB guy, simple way for me to do it would be

```
/* Query to purge log tables older than 60 days */

delete from AUDITLOG where timestamp < trunc(sysdate) - 60;

delete from TRANSACTIONLOG Where timestamp < trunc(sysdate) - 60;
```

As the number of records may be in thousands( clob xml might also be big), I am still not sure if it's the best way to do it. Another way that I am thinking of is to create a primary key with auto sequence and do a max of it to delete the rows.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Your approach seems OK to me. The timestamps are indexed and the statements should be able to use the indexes.

Comment: A frame challenge first: "Is there a need to delete the logs?" You said that the "number of records may be in thousdands"; this is a tiny amount of data (unless your `CLOB` values are particularly large) and you could look at whether the benefit of retaining the log data is greater than the hassle of managing a separate process to delete it and losing that information forever.

Comment: If the number of records is in the thousands, even the tens of thousands you probably don't have any worries. Even if it's the millions, you kick off a background job and forget about it. But I agree with @MT0 that it's worth considering whether you really need to delete these logs. Having log records going back for years can be useful for troubleshooting and diagnosis

Comment: I wonder if people actually worry about optimizing *delete* queries.

Comment: Better solution: partition the log table based on your TIMESTAMP field, then just drop the partitions which are more than two months old.

Answer (score 5):

A frame challenge first: "Is there a need to delete the logs?"

You said that the "number of records may be in thousdands"; this is a tiny amount of data (unless your `CLOB` values are particularly large) and you could look at whether the benefit of retaining the log data is greater than the hassle of managing a separate process to delete it and losing that information forever.

---

If you do decide that you need to delete the logs then create a recurring scheduled job that deletes the out-of-date rows every day (or whatever frequency you deem appropriate).

Something like (untested):

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name             => 'delete_out_of_date_logs_job',
    job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action           => 'BEGIN
DELETE FROM AUDITLOG
WHERE  timestamp < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL ''60'' DAY;
DELETE FROM TRANSACTIONLOG
WHERE  timestamp < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL ''60'' DAY;
END;',
    start_date           => TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
    repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY;', 
    enabled              =>  TRUE,
    comments             => 'Daily log deletion'
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: Do you have to COMMIT the operation?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit As I said, its untested (as I don't have an Oracle instance where I can create jobs at the moment) but shows the general structure of the solution. If you test it and do find you do need a `COMMIT` statement then just add it to the end of the anonymous block.

Comment: I don't think they mention it in the documentation, but dbms_scheduler jobs auto commit when they finish. Which makes sense, because they run in a separate session.